# after toggle menu goes behind the images

Tags: html, css

on normal screen the menu is before the content but after reducing the width of browser when the nav toggles and menu is displayed then on clicking on menu the nav thts displayed goes behind the content

also on load i want that the selected menu be having same color as of hover in this case #bbeecc...how do i get tht

```
    .page-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.header {
    background-color: #00FF00;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
body{ -webkit-animation: bugfix infinite 1s; }
@-webkit-keyframes bugfix { from {padding:0;} to {padding:0;} }

#toggle, .toggle { display: none; }


/* micro clearfix */
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { display: table; content: ""; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.toggle{ 
    z-index: 2; 
}


/* reset padding and margin where necessary etc. */
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    z-index: 2; 
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:x-larger;

}

/* just some quick demo styles for color whatnot */
nav {
    background: #efefef;
    color: white;
    z-index: 2;
}

nav ul ul {
    background: #efefef;
    z-index: 2; 
    width:150px;
}

nav ul ul ul {
    background: #efefef;
    z-index: 2; 
}

nav a  {
    color: white;
    white-space:nowrap;

}

nav a:hover  {
    background: ##bbeecc;

}

/* important functional styles */
nav > ul:after {
    /* clear the float */
    content:'';
    clear:both;
    display: block;
}

nav li  {
    /* for the topmost level we want them to float.  will be overridden */
    float:left;
    font-size: large;

}

nav li a {
    /* always apply padding and display block to the a.  better user experience. */
    display:block;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: large;

}

nav li ul li {
    /* overridden floating here */
    float: none;
    font-size: large;

}

/* here is where all the positioning takes place */
nav li {
    position:relative;
}

nav li ul {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0; /* for top most level lets align to the left */
    top: 100%; /* and have it at the bottom of the parent */
    display:none; /* hide initialy */
}

nav li ul li ul {
    left: 100%; /* for grandchild level lets align to the right of the list item */
    top: 0; /* and have it at the top of the parent li */
}

nav ul li a:hover + ul,
nav ul li a + ul:hover {
    /* show only if the element or the immediately preceding anchor is hovered*/
    display:block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){


    ul{
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background: #efefef;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    z-index: 3; 
    }

    nav {
    height:40px;
    z-index: 3; 
    }

    nav ul ul {
    background: #efefef;
    z-index: 3; 
}

nav ul ul ul {
    background: #efefef;
    z-index: 3; 
}
    nav a  {
    color: white;

}
    nav ul{

    width:200px;
    z-index: 3; 
    }   

    ul li { 
    float:none;
    display: block; 
    width: auto; 
    margin: 0 0 0 0px;
    height: auto; 
    font-size:12px;

    }

    ul li a { 
    float:none;
    display: block; 
    width: auto; 
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;    
    color:#fff; 
    height: auto;  
    }   

/* here is where all the positioning takes place */
    nav li {
        position:relative;
        }

    nav li ul {
        position:absolute;
        left: 100%; /* for top most level lets align to the left */
        top: 0%; /* and have it at the bottom of the parent */
        display:block; /* hide initialy */
    }

    nav li ul li {
    position:relative;
    }

    nav li ul li ul {
        left: 100%; /* for grandchild level lets align to the right of the list item */
        top: -25%; /* and have it at the top of the parent li */
    }

    .toggle { display: block; position: relative; user-select: none;z-index: 3;  }

    #toggle:checked ~ ul { display: block; opacity: 1;z-index: 3; }

    ul li a:hover, ul li a:focus{
    background: ##bbeecc;
    }
    nav ul li a:hover + ul,
    nav ul li a + ul:hover {
        /* show only if the element or the immediately preceding anchor is hovered*/
        display:block;  
        opacity:1; 
        z-index: 3;     
    }
    .toggle:after {
    content: 'MENU';
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: x-large;

    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #efefef;
    z-index: 3; 
    }

    .toggle:hover:after{
    background: #efefef;
    }

    #toggle:checked + .toggle:after{
        content: 'CLOSE MENU';
        z-index: 3; 

    }

}
```

my html is as

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="styletest.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
<div class="page-wrap"> 
    <header class="header">        

     <nav class="nav">
       <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
      <label for="toggle" class="toggle" data-open="MENU" data-close="Close Menu" onclick></label>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>                 
    </nav>

     </header>

     <article ">

         <div><img src="images/3.jpg"  alt=""/></div>
         <div><img src="images/3.jpg"  alt=""/></div>
         <div><img src="images/3.jpg"  alt=""/></div>
         <div><img src="images/3.jpg"  alt=""/></div>
         <div><img src="images/3.jpg"  alt=""/></div>

     </article>


  <footer class="footer">
  Copyright
  </footer>

</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked the `z-index` of all the elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to apply a `z-index` to a non-positioned element.

`z-index` will only work if you are using a value other than the default `static` for an element

```
nav ul{
    width:200px;
    z-index: 3;

    position: relative; /* add this */ 
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uL9B8/)

Comment: thanx but what about the second part " on load i want that the selected menu be having same color as of hover in this case #bbeecc...how do i get tht"

Answer (score 0):

you should add `position: relative` to your `ul`

```
.menu{
    position: relative;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4B2G6/)

Comment: cool...but what abt the second part  on load i want that the selected menu be having same color as of hover in this case #bbeecc...how do i get tht

Answer (score 0):

To use z-index you must specify the position property too.

i have added a position:relative to your ul .

1. ul {
       list-style-type: none;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0px;
       position:relative;
       z-index: 2;  }